# VSTS deployment to multiple app services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ms-release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using VSTS with TFS repository for hosting my code. The solution is a Asp.Net core solution and contains couple of projects. I have two projects in the solution that goes to different App Services - one will be deployed to a Web App and other to an API App.

Question is how do I configure a single build definition / release definition that deploys these artifacts. Currently, I have two definitions - one for each and I would like to have one. How can I go about configuring this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can create publish profile (right click a project => Publish) with the same name for these projects (relative path for package location, such as `<DesktopBuildPackageLocation>..\..\a\WebApp</DesktopBuildPackageLocation>`). With this way, the web app published result will be in **different folders**.
2. Specify MSBuild Arguments of Visual Studio Build task will be like this: `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="[profile name]"`.
3. Add Publish Build Artifacts to publish these web app published result (e.g. Path to Publish:`$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`)
4. Create a new release definition
5. Add two Deploy app tasks (e.g. Azure app service deploy)
6. Specify corresponding package to deploy

Update:

Using multiple Publish Tasks to publish each package is ok too (Do not need the publish profile).

Comment: Thanks, sounds promising. Let me look into it and get back.

Comment: @NitinRastogi Feel free to post the result here.

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT -  I was able to complete the functionality based on the above cues. I had to use two Publish Tasks in build definition, each generating it's own named package. And then in release definition, two tasks for deploying to Azure App Services. I didn't have to execute Step 1, and 2, and followed the rest. Would you want to update the answer as I believe 1 and 2 are not needed - just two publish tasks?. And I shall mark your response as an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with the "ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)" Build Template. By default, a single package is created for all Function Apps in the solution.
2. Modify the Build Solution task msbuild arguments so that a package is created for each Function App projects

   **From**:
   `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"`

   **To**
   `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"`
3. Run the build and review the publish artifacts, you should see multiple zip files in the package, one for each of the Function Apps
4. Now, for each Function App you want to deploy, add an 'Deploy Azure App Service' task to your Release definition
5. Update the 'Deploy Azure App Service' task, package or folder, to:
   `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/Your.Project.FunctionApp.zip`